# How do I use `NestedArray::getValue()` to get a value from an array?

Tags: 9

I see the [`NestedArray::getValue()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21NestedArray.php/function/NestedArray%3A%3AgetValue) but the documentation isn't clear. How do I use this to get a value out of a nested array, such as form state or raw form input?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array like this:

```
$my_array = [
  'key1' => [
    'key1.1' => 'a',
    'key1.2' => 'b',
    'key1.3' => 'c',
  ],
  'key2' => [
    'key2.1' => 'x',
    'key2.2' => 'y',
    'key2.3' => 'z',
  ],
];
```

And you want to get to `$my_array['key2']['key2.2']` dynamically (e.g., using an array of `#parents` from a form element), you can use `NestedArray::getValue($my_array, ['key2', 'key2.2'])`.

As a bonus, this method returns a *reference* to the value so you can also change what you get back and the change will be reflected in the array.